# how can I filter html tags in python?

Tags: python, html, filter

here is the html

```
<section class=\"xmt-style-block\" data-id=\"330057\" data-style-type=\"5\" data-tools=\"3434\">
abc cba abc cba
<p style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;box-sizing: border-box;">
<br/> pp pp</p></section>
<section class=\"xmt-style-block\" data-id=\"330057\" data-style-type=\"5\" data-tools=\"3434\">abc cba abc cba<p style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;box-sizing: border-box;"><br/> pp pp</p></section>
```

I want to filter "class" "data-id" "data-style-type" "data-tools"

only left `<section>abc cba abc cba <p> pp pp</p></section><section>abc cba abc cba <p> pp pp</p></section>`

How can I do this in python? Thank you!

Comment: HTML is not code. It's a markup language.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck at? Find some HTML/XML parser and just do it.

Comment: Why was the dupe removed for this question?

Comment: sorry. I have updated my question.can you help again?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<section class=\"xmt-style-block\" data-id=\"330057\" data-style-type=\"5\" data-tools=\"3434\">abc cba abc cba</section>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> section = soup.find_all('section')[0]
>>> del section['class'], section['data-id'], section['data-tools'], section['data-style-type']
>>> str(section)
'<section>abc cba abc cba</section>'
```

You can adjust `soup.find_all('section')[0]` to use `id` or however you search / loop through it

Comment: sorry. I have updated my question.can you help again?

Comment: @user3751111 You could easily figure this out just loop through `soup.find_all('section')` and do the same thing each time

Answer (score 0):

Taking the data in your question literally, this solution is not elegant, but it works.

I put your html in a file called *sample_html.html* and then in the same folder I made a python script called *filter_section.py*. Here is the code of this script:

```
# Get file name of code you want to filter
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "sample_html.html"

# Create a file handle, like opening the file...
f_handle = open(fname)

# Define your new file that you will write to...
f_new= open("new_html.html","w+")

# Loop through each line in file
for line in f_handle:
    # If line doesn't start with what you want to replace then write line to file and continue
    if not line.startswith("<section class"):
        f_new.write(line)
        continue
    # You want to replace this line so split it into list of strings
    strings =  line.split()
    # Set new value for first string in list
    strings[0] = '<section>'
    # Delete the strings you don't want, this is what you are filtering out
    del strings[1:5]
    # Join the strings to a new line and write it to file
    new_line = " ".join(strings)
    f_new.write(new_line)
# Close yor new file
f_new.close()
```

The output of *new_html.html* will not have those attributes in the section elements